# how to add touch listener and get position of an actor in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an actor which contains an image, I am adding this actor to my stage, with this code, this is my actor code

```
public O(sosgame game){
    super.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    texture = Assets.o;
    setWidth(texture.getWidth());
    setHeight(texture.getHeight());
    setBounds(10, 180, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
}
```

After I add my actor to my stage, I want to get its position in that screen, so I can move and drag my actor around the screen, I added input listener with this code, by the way, "o" is the instance name of my actor class

```
o.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            System.out.println(x + " " + y);
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    });
```

My problem is, when I touch my actor to drag it around the screen, I get the x and y values of my actor, not the actor's positon in screen, I should get the position of my actor inside the screen, how can I manage this, thank you

Comment: Are you using camera? `camera.project(Vector3)` gives you the `screenCoordinates` of that given `Vector3`, `camera.unproject(Vector3)` returns the worldcoordinates.

Comment: I need to get the coordinates of my actor in that screen, my screen is 200,300 but my actor is 100,200, I should get 100,200

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#localToStageCoordinates%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2%29

Comment: @noone no, not that one :) but thank you :)

Comment: So if a `Stage` is 10 wide and 10 heigh, and your `Actor` is in the middle of the screen you want to get 5,5 right? So you have to use `camera.unproject(Vector3)`. Note, that a `Stage` has its own camera: `stage.getCamera()`. If you are using latest version you should use `Viewport` but i think @noone can tell you more about that.